# Navigation menu will not link to my other pages

Tags: html

I have all of the other page files saved together in one folder and each one works individually but, when I click the other menu options it takes me to an error page. I used HTML and Sublime 2.  The webpage locating the menu directory seems to be my main issue.

#

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
 </head>

 <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="lawncare.html">Lawn Care</a></li>
                <li><a href="homeexterior.html">Home Exterior</a></li>
                <li><a href="kitchen.html">Kitchen</a></li>
                <li><a href="homeinterior.html">Home Interior</a></li>
                <li><a href="testyourself.html">Test Yourself!</a></li>

(The area above is whats not working, all the files are located in the same directory, but when i hit them on the webpage, safari, chrome, etc says the file cannot be found)
            </ul>
         </nav>

<h1>How to Protect Your Home from Pests</h1>

<img src="http://www.peterandpaulspestcontrol.com.au/files/media/thumbcache/011/c11/60b/ant.jpg">

    <section>
        <article>
        <p> Pests are very bad. They should be kept away from your stuff. This paragraph will be an intro and describe they lay out of the information.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you have a folder name example "test" inside test you need to to all home.html, lawncare.html, homeexterior.html, kitchen.html, homeinterior.html, testyourself.html And each html contain this nav structure.

Comment: In which folder is above page and in which is the other files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your files (`lawncare.html`, `homeexterior.html`, etc.) are all located in the same folder as `home.html` and each other, or the links won't work.

Alternatively, if you want your HTML files to be in another folder, you'll have to add that folder path before your file name in your links. For example, if you have them in a folder called `pages`, your links would look like this:

```
<li><a href="pages/home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="pages/lawncare.html">Lawn Care</a></li>
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<A HREF="pages/about.html">About this site</A>
```